# React prop containing function is not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I want to pass a function down to a child component - should be really simple. Here is my render:

```
  render() {
    const responses = this.state.responses;
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {
          responses
          ? <ScrollView style={{flex: 1}}>
              <Header />
                <Wrapper responses={responses} sendMessage={this.sendMessage}/>
              <Footer/>
            </ScrollView>
          : <Loading />
        }
      </View>
    );
  }
```

and here is my constructor where I bind the function to "this":

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      "sensors": null,
      "responses": null
    };

    this.connectSockets = this.connectSockets.bind(this);
    this.sendMessage = this.sendMessage.bind(this)
  }
```

The function I want to pass looks like this:

```
  sendMessage(techPhoneNumber, dangerMessageForTech) {
    return SMS.text(techPhoneNumber, dangerMessageForTech);
  }
```

However, the child component is getting an empty object, and when I break on the "Wrapper" component and hover over "sendMessage" prop I see:

```
"message": "sendMessage is not defined"
```

When I hover over "responses" I see the data. I am not sure what I am missing here... help?

**EDIT** this has nothing to do with the SMS module because when I try to pass any other function down I get the same result... I am using react native but it should be the same no?

I am accessing sendMessage like so in Wrapper component:

```
export default Wrapper = ({responses}, sendMessage) => {
    //do stuff
}
```

Comment: Could you add how you access `sendMessage` in your `Wrapper` component?

Comment: I added that info but it seems to me that since the prop is giving the error "sendMessage is not defined" in App when I break on Wrapper and hover over "sendMessage" prop that the issue occurs before it is passed down

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just importing the SMS module into the component that needed it and calling it inside a function in the "onPress" prop and that solved the immediate issue. I will look into it further and maybe post a bounty If I cannot pass any functions down as props when deconstructing the "props" object correctly

Answer (score 2):

Ah, there is a problem with your code,

this is the correct way:

```
export default Wrapper = ({responses, sendMessage}) => {
    //do stuff
}
```

the reason behind this is your wrapper component is getting only one Object as its argument with `sendMessage` and `responses` as its properties.

Another correct way will be:

```
export default Wrapper = (props) => {
    const {responses, sendMessage} = props; // or directly using props.responses and props.sendMessage
    //do stuff
}
```

Comment: This is correct I get that: ({responses, sendMessage}) deconstructs "props" into the properties... However even after making the change it still is not working

Comment: Ok is your `sendMessage` function is defined in that parent class component? If so where you want to use it? It’s actually really simple thing and very commonly used way.

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
export default Wrapper = ({responses, sendMessage}) => {
    //do stuff
}
```

OR:

Access it using props.

```
export default Wrapper = (props) => {
        //do stuff
        //props.responses, 
        //props.sendMessage()
    }
```

Comment: It is true that I messed that up (tired) but even after fixing it snedMessage is STILL not defined when breaking before we even get into child component "Wrapper"

Comment: Please call it from wrapper and then check. For now just check in console. It should work

Comment: I have done so. Unfortunately it still does not work. Breaking on the "Wrapper" parent component "App" before the function is passed down shows ""message": "sendMessage is not defined" and the same shows when I go into the actual component and break there.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, I think this is okay:

```
render() {
const responses = this.state.responses;
return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    {
      responses
      ? <ScrollView style={{flex: 1}}>
          <Header />
            <Wrapper responses={responses} sendMessage={this.sendMessage}/>
          <Footer/>
        </ScrollView>
      : <Loading />
    }
  </View>
);
}
```

But I have corrected this

```
 constructor(props) {
super(props);

this.state = {
  "sensors": null,
  "responses": null
};

this.connectSockets = props.connectSockets.bind(this);
this.sendMessage = props.sendMessage.bind(this)
 }
```

Comment: I don't think so... I've never heard of binding that way and anyway, I tried it and the whole app broke with "cannot read property "bind" of undefined"

Comment: I use functions passed down from parent to a child directly this way : This is your code: props.connectSockets.bind(this); This is mine: onPress={handleChange.bind(this, value, item)}; Mine is triggered by onPress button event.

Comment: It does not have 'props.' because I copied the code from a stateless component.

Comment: Alternatively, use this.connectSockets=props.connectSockets; then this.connectSockets.bind(this);

Answer (score 0):

Try using arrow functions instead of bind

```
sendMessage = (techPhoneNumber, dangerMessageForTech) => {
return SMS.text(techPhoneNumber, dangerMessageForTech); }
```

and

```
<Wrapper responses={responses} sendMessage={this.sendMessage}/>
```

Comment: I tired that first. Same result

Answer (score 0):

Change your Wrapper component to

```
> export default Wrapper=({responses,sendMessage}){

//Do stuff

}
```